# How to use angular.module run() to run with <video>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am new to angular js. i have a html5 video element which src will bind dynamically. the src is a url of api call which need auth token to be send along with the request. i want to send the token along with video request or before the request. can it be send using angular.module run() ? Please help.

```
    <div>
                                            <video ng-app="previewVideo" id="videoPlayer" src="" width="420" style="display: none;" type="video/mp4"
                                                class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls>
                                            </video>
                                        </div>

 angular.module('previewVideo', []).run(function () {
            debugger;
            var _beforeRequest = _.isFunction(videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest);
            videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest = function (options) {
                if (_beforeRequest) {
                    options = _beforeRequest(options);
                }
                if (authToken) {
                    options.headers = options.headers || {};
                    options.headers.Authorization = 'Token ' + token;
                }
                return options;
            };
        });
```